# Float loses precision in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, precision

I am storing some value in Float variable in swift 3. But when I actually use this value from the variable, it loses it precision. I have tried it in playground. It gives me final output as:
152.399994 instead of 152.4 (or 152.40)

Please consider below code:

```
let feetToInchMultiplier: Float = 12
  let inchToCentimeterMultiplier: Float = 2.54

func heightInCentimeters(_ feet: Float, inches: Float) -> Float {
    //Convert in Centemeters
    let totalInches: Float = (feet * feetToInchMultiplier) + inches
    let centimeters: Float = totalInches * inchToCentimeterMultiplier
    return centimeters
}

heightInCentimeters(5, inches: 0)
```

If anyone facing this issue please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Float variable always return standard float value with predefine precisions you have to manually change the precisions you want to show. Change your `heightInCentimeters` method with below and you will get desired out put.

```
func heightInCentimeters(_ feet: Float, inches: Float) -> Float {
    //Convert in Centemeters
    let totalInches: Float = (feet * feetToInchMultiplier) + inches
    let centimeters: Float = totalInches * inchToCentimeterMultiplier

    return Float(String(format: "%.2f",centimeters))!
}
```